# Delete multiple table rows from the PostgreSQL table present in the CSV file

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, psycopg2

I want to delete multiple table rows that are present in the CSV file

I'm able to make a connection to the db.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=dbendpoint, port=portinfo, database=databasename, user=dbusername, password=password)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

I'm able to read the CSV file and store the contents in the dataframe

```
dfOutput = spark.read.format("text").option("delimiter",",").option("header", "true").option("mode","FAILFAST").option("compression","None").csv(inputFile)
```

I think I have to convert my dataframe into tuple to use it into psycopg2.

Now I'm unable to proceed forward.

I'm new to psycopg2, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is, what information do you need from a csv row to uniquely identify a database row that must be deleted?

Comment: It can be 2 primary key columns or whole row, this part I'm able to fetch, just that how to use it to delete from the db I'm not able to figure out.